# How to properly set session keys for Relay and Parachain with custom keys

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, relay-chain

### The Goal:

Deploying a Relay Chain with Custom Validator Keys, that a Parachain can start collation successfully.

### The Issue:

Using the `key` subcommand in the Relay, I wasn't able to properly insert the Session Keys to the Relay nodes' keystore.

The Relay with 2 validators was working fine, producing and finalizing blocks, but when I deployed a Parachain it outputted a `WARN`:  `collation wasn't advertised to any validator`.

And it started to output the WARN for 5 minutes +- until it started to output an error. Finally I haven't found any mention whatsoever in how to do so.

Comment: Hey, can you add the command you are using to start the collator?

Comment: RUST_LOG=runtime ./target/release/parachain \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain para-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/tokenizer \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
--name PARA2000 \
--rpc-port 9022 \
--unsafe-ws-external \
--rpc-methods=unsafe \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-cors=all \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain 2v-raw.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977

Comment: I read your comment about using `--alice`, I think something could be wrong in the chain-spec. Can you trying with zombienet (https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet) ?

Comment: My builds have custom build-spec commands to receive seed and generate the needed keys for the Relay and in the Parachain as well. What is interesting is, when I make the ChainSpec using `//Alice //Bob` as seed in the Relay and starting with `--alice` and `--bob` flags in the Relay, and in the Parachain using the same Genesis, Wasm and ChainSpec with the Alice keys inserted running the Para with the `--alice` flag it works, the collation starts. Which by this I started to think that I'm missing something when inserting keys on my Relay Validtator Nodes.

Comment: Deleting the question text makes the post not that valuable :/ please do update or delete yge post completely?

Comment: Would you mind providing the solution anytime soon? We have the same issue, asked here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/adding-pallet-gilt-to-a-running-chain-bricks-the-chain

Comment: I've submitted the solution, soon they'll review and approve so you can solve your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreRibeiro 

Comment: You should answer your own question though. The question should not contain a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Solution:

After trying a lot of things, I've found from an RPC call that there's 7 keys needed for each Validator node. Those are, `gran` `babe` `imon` `para` `asgn` `audi` `beef`. And for each key-type there's a scheme, there's a table to reference.

| Key-Type | Scheme |
| --- | --- |
| gran | ed25519 |
| babe | sr25519 |
| imon | sr25519 |
| para | sr25519 |
| asgn | sr25519 |
| audi | sr25519 |
| beef | ecdsa |

Insert them like this,

```
./target/release/polkadot key insert \
--base-path <path for this validator> \
--chain <raw relay chainSpec> \
--scheme <see table> \
--suri "<mnemonic of this validator>" \
--key-type <see table>
```

Pay attention to the `base-path` you're choosing, you need separate paths for different validators.
And to each path, you insert 7 keys using the same validators' private `seed`.

### Parachain Session Keys:

In the Para, run the node and specify a RPC port to make a call later on.

```
./target/release/<parachain binary> --collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain <raw parachainSpec> \
--base-path /tmp/<para>/<path> \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
--rpc-port 9022 \
--unsafe-ws-external \
--rpc-methods=unsafe \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-cors=all \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain relay-raw.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977 \
--bootnodes /ip4/<relay bootnode ip>/tcp/30333/p2p/<bootnode peerId>
```

Using this command as an example, the port open for RPC was **9022** so the insert key call should be:

```
curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["aura", "<private seed in hex>", "<public key in hex>"],"id":1 }' http://127.0.0.1:9022
```

> The private and public key here should be the **collator** keys. And it's for **aura**. So it is using the `sr25519` scheme.

And it's output:

```
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this warning is not related to the session keys. Try add more validators to the relaychain.

---

And if you are using `--alice` or something like that. You don't need to insert the key manually. These are well-known keys.

---

And if you want to insert your custom keys, check the runtime session keys configurations.

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/220bc559f064d38485d5a21e2ba91a8a237e9d16/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L168-L172

Let's take parachain-template as an example. As you can see from the link, you only need to insert the `Aura` key.

Comment: When I used the `--alice` flag on the parachain, I didn't insert the keys manually. I'm saying that, something must be wrong on the Relay Chain side (on the session keys probably?) because I got the same error `Collation wasn't advertised to any validator.`

Comment: Did you try adding more validators to the relaychain. If the validators count too low, it won't assign validators to the parachain.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with 3 validators on the Relay Chain but got the same error. Should I need to insert on the Relay validator nodes any kind/type of keys from my Collator?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Could you share your relaychain and parachain code?

Comment: Interesting, so it should work when using `--alice`. I can't share the code sorry, but I'm trying a different approach, I'm building the v0.9.29 from scratch, and will just edit the ChainSpec files. The modifications I made were only in the `chain_spec.rs` and in `commands.rs` just to add a new build-spec option that receives the seed input as a CLI argument.