# Adding pallet-gilt to a running chain breaks the chain

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, runtime-upgrade

I am running a simple 2-validator substrate chain with my own keys (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate, branch = polkadot-v0.9.27). I have removed `pallet-gilt` from the runtime and what I am trying to do is a runtime upgrade (with the `setCode` extrinsic) and add `pallet-gilt` to the runtime. The upgrade is successful but the chain breaks just before the `intake_duration` of pallet-gilt. The error I am getting is the following:

```bash
2022-11-04 16:04:18 panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 299', /Users/zycon/cherry/substrate/frame/gilt/src/lib.rs:600:28
2022-11-04 16:04:18 Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x4a57eb - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
```

The function that contains the line of code that breaks is the following:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5bfdbab8ba28523ef10e365627fed64ef2b77cbf/frame/gilt/src/lib.rs#L585-L660

That only happens when I try to add `pallet-gilt` to an already running chain. If I add `pallet-gilt` to genesis and start the chain with the pallet, I have no errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `enlarge` function is called by `pursue_target`, which is called periodically (every `n % IntakePeriod` blocks) by the `on_initialize` hook.

If you check [line 600](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5bfdbab8ba28523ef10e365627fed64ef2b77cbf/frame/gilt/src/lib.rs#L600) (exactly where the code breaks), you'll see that `enlarge` is trying to read the `qs` array, where `qs` is the current state of the `QueueTotals` Storage Item (read up on [Rust Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) to understand how `mutate` is working to modify `QueueTotals`).

The problem is that because the `gilt` pallet was introduced via Runtime Upgrade (and most likely, you didn't perform any Storage Migration), the `QueueTotals` Storage Item is empty. Therefore, the pallet's Rust code breaks when it tries to read the empty `qs` array.

> 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 299'

If you check the pallet's [`GenesisBuild`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b2a914c09739478c63d318f6b294901a3290e548/frame/gilt/src/lib.rs#L278), you'll see that `QueueTotals` is being populated there. So when you add `gilt: Default::default(),` into [`GenesisConfig`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/378a3e5ae41df1af0ef1a66b2076342bce678688/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L135) of your `node/src/chain_spec.rs` (which I'm assuming you did), the `QueueTotals` is properly bootstrapped at genesis and the pallet runs smoothly whenever the `on_initialize` hook is triggered.

The only solution to this problem is to implement a [Storage Migration](https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/substrate-how-to-guides/docs/storage-migrations/nicks-migration/) to be performed during your Runtime Upgrade. It shouldn't be too complex, all you have to do is reproduce whatever the pallet's `GenesisBuild` is already doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and come back to you. Cheers!